# Not able to compile Ziparchive library (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode4.5, unzip, php-ziparchive

I need to download and unzip a file in my Xcode project, 
I am using Ziparchive (https://code.google.com/p/ziparchive/downloads/detail?name=ZipArchive.zip) to do so,instead of following every step I am getting compilation error as below:

```
/Developer/AR/vuforia-sdk-ios-2-6-8/samples/ARDemo/minizip/ioapi.c:68:18: Redefinition of 'fopen_file_func' as different kind of symbol
/Developer/AR/vuforia-sdk-ios-2-6-8/samples/ARDemo/minizip/ioapi.c:68:35: Use of undeclared identifier 'opaque'
/Developer/AR/vuforia-sdk-ios-2-6-8/samples/ARDemo/minizip/ioapi.c:68:58: Expected ';' after top level declarator
/Developer/AR/vuforia-sdk-ios-2-6-8/samples/ARDemo/minizip/ioapi.c:72:1: Expected unqualified-id
/Developer/AR/vuforia-sdk-ios-2-6-8/samples/ARDemo/minizip/ioapi.c:90:17: Redefinition of 'fread_file_func' as different kind of symbol
Developer/AR/vuforia-sdk-ios-2-6-8/samples/ARDemo/minizip/ioapi.c:90:42: Use of undeclared identifier 'stream'; did you mean 'strcat'?
  Developer/AR/vuforia-sdk-ios-2-6-8/samples/ARDemo/minizip/ioapi.c:90:50: Use of undeclared identifier 'buf'
/Developer/AR/vuforia-sdk-ios-2-6-8/samples/ARDemo/minizip/ioapi.c:95:1: Expected unqualified-id
```

I dont have a clue how to compile it successfully, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, it happens because I have an incorrect Prefix file. 
It was including objective c imports outside the "#ifdef **OBJC**" block
So that there was no problem when all classes were objetctive-C classes but it didn't compile when I add the C classes of minizip.

Just moving all the imports in the prefix file inside the obj block and voilà!

```
#ifdef __OBJC__
    #import <Availability.h>
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#endif
```

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Please Add the FrameWork `libz.dylib` in your project and solve your problem

**Project setting -> Target-> Build Phases -> Linked Frameworks and Libraries -> select ibz.dylib**

Comment: Already linked it, libz.dylib and libz.1.2.5.dylib, all the frameworks are added, as I said I followed every step, still the problem !

Comment: please send your email id

Comment: However I am using "Compile sources as - > Objective C++", that might not be the problem I suspect !

Comment: rohit.kashyap@in.bosch.com

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution,I am using Metaio SDK for Augmented Reality which has a compile dependancy, it can only be compiled as  "Compile sources as - > Objective C++" and this was the reason creating the problem, Ziparchive compiled fine otherwise, now to merge both in the same project I made Ziparchive as a STATIC LIBRARY and linked it in Xcode, it solved the problem.